# jQuery change class of single div between three seperate styles with two buttons

Tags: jquery, css, html

I would like to add a class("ex") on landing or similarly through jQuery.

from button ['#ity'] I'd like to toggle a 2nd class ("arc")

from button ['#act'] I'd like to toggle a 3rd class ("nex")

all are inside the same div as ("ex") which is located at (".her:first")

("ex") has a clickable link area ("a.fr") and a separate div ("mid") inside it,
any thoughts regarding proper syntax for those area's are appreciated.

I've added fadeToggle and rearranged my syntax throughout today to no avail
I cannot find a solution or manage to get it working properly.

This is the jQuery I was working on...very sloppy and of course incorrect at this time.
As I do not completely know how to fix it I've just posted as is.

```
$(".her:first").addClass("ex");

$('a[href="#act"]').click(function(){
    $(".her:first").fadeToggle("1200", function(){
        $(".her:first").toggleClass("arc nex");
    });
});

$('a[href="#act"]').click(function(){
    $(".her:first").toggleClass(function() {
        if ($(this).is($('a[href="#ity"]'))) {
            .toggleClass("arc");
        } else {
            .toggleClass("nex");
        }
    });
});
```

//I'm just posting my CSS for reference//

```
.ex {   
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(../img/el.png);
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-left:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.mid  {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('../img/pen.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

a.fr {
    background-color:rgba(0,20,44, 0.1);
    background-position: left;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left:center;
    left: 592px;
    top: 54%;
    width: 136px;
    height: 136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.her { }

.nex {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(../img/test2.png);
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-left:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

//--------My HTML----------//

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>blah.com</title>

<!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favo.png">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>

<!-- Including the Questrial"  font from Google's Font Directory -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" />

<!-- Enabling HTML5 support for Internet Explorer -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="bge">

<header>
<h1><a href="http://blah.com"</a>blah</h1>
<h2>Welcome</h2>
</header>

<div class="boo">
<nav>
<ul class="vNav">

<li id="lookbook"><a href="...." target="_self">LBOOK</a></li>
<li id="quality"><a href="#ity" target="_self">ITY</a></li>
<li id="boutique"><a href="...." target="_self">QUE</a></li>
<li id="contact"><a href="#act" target="_self">ACT</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div class="her">
<div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I greatly appreciate any thoughts and your time.

Comment: I don't know what this means. `I would like to add a class("ex") on landing or similarly through jQuery.` What is landing? Why is it similar to jQuery?

Comment: @mrtsherman By landing I meant home page, basically. In that regard I mean to cause the event similarly... as if I can addClass or prompt the home pages css to load through jquery as opposed to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some clean-up based on what you said you'd like to do and this is what I have so far, assuming your HTML is in place:

[edit: made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stoefflerj/WUNaB/) to avoid clutter]

As you can see, I eliminated `fadeToggle()`.  I'm not exactly sure what you were trying to accomplish with that, but what it does is displays or hides (with animation) the element it is called on.  The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) is always a great place to start if you're unsure about something.  I also simplified the click handlers you had by making a distinct handler for each button as you can see.

Could you post your HTML so I can see the layout of the elements and possibly offer you some more help?  If you have any questions feel free to comment.

Comment: First off thank you. I have added my HTML and I'm currently looking over your answer and processing where my mistakes were.

Comment: The reasoning I used the fadeToggle was to create a fade from one style's transition to the next, the only way I was getting the fade working at the time was using fadeToggle...for some reason the fadeIn was not working

Comment: I'd like the events to toggle and replace the content regardless what content is currently active...like on/off buttons except if another button is on inside the div the click event will always replace its content. At this time when "act" is active clicking on "ity" does not replace it, but when "ity" is active "act" replaces it...I'd like it to work in the same manner through both events. I'm going to look it over of course but I just wanted to type to be clearer with my question as I may not be correctly wording or understanding how to word what I am attempting to achieve.

Comment: Check out the [jsFiddle I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/stoefflerj/WUNaB/).  I put in some different styles so you could see what the buttons do and the animations.  Feel free to play around with it.

Comment: your help is greatly appreciated, due to your code I have it working exactly as how I described last night:)TY ... I only had to place a removeClass in for the buttons to function properly back and forth...I am experimenting with fade's to attempt to get the animation I wanted. I checked this right on time, I'm going to go over to jsFiddle right now so I can get a clearer vision of how the animations are coded. Enjoy your day!

Comment: You're most welcome.  As I mentioned on the jsFiddle, the animated toggleClass I used requires jQuery UI, which is not included in the regular jQuery library.  So if you choose to use it you'll need to include the following script source URL as you did with the other one: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: as I take this a step further I'm not understanding how to [append/add/attach??] different HTML inside of the different class elements in order to change content. I am coding an <a> link with these properties .html('<a class="free" href="http://blog.myblog.com" target="_self"></a>'). I am having trouble encoding the html to attach itself to only class "ex" and toggle with it/ as opposed to attaching itself to the document

Comment: There's an unnecessary semicolon in your code after the href attribute.  Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/ might help. I'm not sure what else to tell you without taking a look at your code.

Comment: if you have the time I could post it, I've used append/appendTo and many others in different ways for a few days to no avail, that's pretty much my situation I'm fresh out of idea's at this time

Comment: I went over and posted the code on jsFiddle here is the link, http://jsfiddle.net/qqfzc/7/ if you have time to look it over it is appreciated and in any regard enjoy your day

Answer (score 0):

The following code is performing the functions for me as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $her = $(".her:first");
var $ity = $('a[href="#ity"]');
var $act = $('a[href="#act"]');

$tree.toggleClass("ex");




$ity.click( function() {
$her.fadeOut(1000, function(){
$her.removeClass("nex").toggleClass("arc").fadeIn(1000);


});});

$act.click( function() {
$her.fadeOut(1000, function(){
$her.removeClass("arc").toggleClass("nex").fadeIn(1000);
});});
```